# Search from a table using values of a column of another table

Tags: sql

Suppose i have two tables.

```
table one:

| col1 |
- - - - -
| do   |
| big  |
| gone |

table two

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
| do   | blah | blah | big  |
| big  | do   | blah | gone |
| blah | blah | blah | blah |
```

how do i search from `table two` such that rows which are displayed contain all values of `col1` of `table one`

for eg. the result for the given situation should be

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
| big  | do   | blah | gone |
```

Comment: A record in table two must have a correspondence to each record in table one for at least one of it columns?

Comment: yes, just as shown in the example.

Comment: @KaranJ.S. . . . What database are you using?

Comment: A very odd problem - once table one has 5 or more distinct values, then there can never be a match.

Comment: @dbenham: it looks like a reduced version of an `exact cover` problem. Let's coin it `inexact cover` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nasty problem...

```
SELECT two.*
  FROM two
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one) =
       (CASE WHEN col1 IN (SELECT * FROM one) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN col2 IN (SELECT * FROM one) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN col3 IN (SELECT * FROM one) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN col4 IN (SELECT * FROM one) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       )
```

The term 'efficiency' should not be mentioned in conjunction with this query.

Comment: . . This doesn't work.  If a row contained the value "big" in three columns, then it would satisfy the condition.  See my answer below.

Comment: Please unaccept this answer so I can remove it, unless you can provide assurance that neither the first nor the third line in the example data could ever appear because the different columns would contain different values (that is, the values in col1..col4 would be all distinct).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the trickiest part of this is guaranteeing that *all* the columns are covered in the second table.  It is not enough just to count them, you also have be sure that all are the set:

```
select t.*
from two t left outer join
     one o1
     on o1.col1 = t.col1 left outer join
     one o2
     on o2.col1 = t.col2 and o2.col1 not in (coalesce(t.col1, '')) left outer join
     one o3
     on o3.col1 = t.col3 and o3.col1 not in (coalesce(t.col1, ''), coalesce(t.col2, '')) left outer join
     one o4
     on o4.col1 = t.col4 and o4.col1 not in (coalesce(t.col1, ''), coalesce(t.col2, ''), coalesce(t.col3, '')) cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from one) const
where const.cnt = ((case when o1.col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when o2.col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when o3.col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when o4.col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                  )
```

This looks up each value in the `one` table, with the proviso that the value has not been seen before.  If there are duplicates in the `one` table, there is question on how to handle them.  Would that mean that the value has to appear that many times?

Comment: It took a while to figure out how this works, but I finally get it. But there is a problem if there are duplicate values in table one. As written, it fails to return what should be matching rows. Changing to `count(distinct col1)` returns duplicates of matching rows.

Comment: Duplicate values in one are not a problem if you select from a CTE that selects distinct values from one.

Comment: @dbenham . . . That is easily fixed by changing the `count(*) as cnt` to `count(distinct col1)` as cnt` in the subquery.

Comment: No, because you then get duplicate rows in your output when duplicate rows from one successfully join to two. I tried to indicate that in my first comment. As I said in my second comment, you can modify all your outer joins to refer to a common table expression that consists of distinct values from one. Here is the [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79fd9/39). See my answer for an alternate approach that pivots the rows in table one into a single row.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes CTE's, and bitoperations (leftshift and OR), as available in postgres (might be present in other DBMSses, too)

```
WITH rnk AS (
    SELECT col1, (rank() OVER (ORDER BY col1))::integer AS rnk
    FROM one
    )
, five AS (
    SELECT t.*
            , 0::integer
            | COALESCE( 1<< o1.rnk, 0)
            | COALESCE( 1<< o2.rnk, 0)
            | COALESCE( 1<< o3.rnk, 0)
            | COALESCE( 1<< o4.rnk, 0)
            AS mask
    FROM two t
    LEFT JOIN rnk o1 ON o1.col1 = t.col1
    LEFT JOIN rnk o2 ON o2.col1 = t.col2
    LEFT JOIN rnk o3 ON o3.col1 = t.col3
    LEFT JOIN rnk o4 ON o4.col1 = t.col4
    )
SELECT * FROM five f5
WHERE f5.mask IN (14)
    ;
```

Update: this one may be a bit cleaner, since is hides the bitshift inside the CTE.

```
WITH xrnk AS (
    SELECT col1, 1::integer << (rank() OVER (ORDER BY col1))::integer AS xrnk
    FROM one
    )
, five AS (
    SELECT t.*
        , ( COALESCE( o1.xrnk, 0)
          | COALESCE( o2.xrnk, 0)
          | COALESCE( o3.xrnk, 0)
          | COALESCE( o4.xrnk, 0)
          ) >> 1
        AS mask
    FROM two t
    LEFT JOIN xrnk o1 ON o1.col1 = t.col1
    LEFT JOIN xrnk o2 ON o2.col1 = t.col2
    LEFT JOIN xrnk o3 ON o3.col1 = t.col3
    LEFT JOIN xrnk o4 ON o4.col1 = t.col4
    )
SELECT * FROM five f5
WHERE f5.mask IN (7)
    ;
```

The simplest solution is always the best:

```
SELECT * FROM two t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM one o
        WHERE o.col1 <> t.col1 AND o.col1 <> t.col2
          AND o.col1 <> t.col3 AND o.col1 <> t.col4
        )
        ;
```

UPDATE: (thanks @dbenham) the simple query is rather sensitive to NULLs in the `two` table, which has to be handled by a bunch of `COALESCE()` wrappers. The 'XxxX' literal is intended to never match, obviously:

```
SELECT * FROM two t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM one o
        WHERE o.col1 <> COALESCE(t.col1, 'XxxX' )
          AND o.col1 <> COALESCE(t.col2, 'XxxX' )
          AND o.col1 <> COALESCE(t.col3, 'XxxX' )
          AND o.col1 <> COALESCE(t.col4, 'XxxX' )
        )
        ;
```

Comment: +1 - ooh, I like the last option as long as none of table two columns are NULL. Strategic use of COALESCE can solve the NULL problem. SQLServer does an excellent job optimizing the query into a left anti semi join. Note - The where clause can be simplified to `where o.col1 not in (t.col1,t.col2,t.col3,t.col4)`. Again, NULL values will require addition of coalesce.

Comment: You are right about the NULLS. The `IN(a,b,c,d)` would work well, too. Finding the righ construct using COALESCE() is hard; caused by the double negation. BTW: the first 2 queries don't suffer from the NULL problem.

Comment: You could use something like `coalesce(t.col1,'x'||o.col1)` to guarantee no match if t.col1 is null.

Comment: You are right again. That would technically/logically be better. But my version is clearer for the human reader, I think. (MMMV)

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what SQL engine you are using - it can make a difference.

I've provided a solution that requires support for the row_number() function. I believe at least Oracle, DB2, and SQLServer all support row_number().

The problem is fairly straight forward once distinct values from table one are pivoted into a single row. There cannot be any matches if more than 4 distinct values exist in table one. It seems there should be a better way to do the pivoting, but I know this solution works.

I've taken pains to make sure the answer returns all rows from two if one is empty, and that duplicate rows in one are ignored.

```
with 
uniqueOne as ( 
  select distinct col1 from one 
),
ranked as (
  select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) seq from uniqueOne
),
vals as (
  select t1.col1 val1, 
         t2.col1 val2, 
         t3.col1 val3, 
         t4.col1 val4
    from (select 1 dummy) dummy
    left join ranked t1 on t1.seq=1
    left join ranked t2 on t2.seq=2
    left join ranked t3 on t3.seq=3
    left join ranked t4 on t4.seq=4
    left join ranked t5 on t5.seq=5
   where t5.seq is null
)
select two.*
  from two
 cross join vals
 where (vals.val1 is null or vals.val1 in (two.col1, two.col2, two.col3, two.col4))
   and (vals.val2 is null or vals.val2 in (two.col1, two.col2, two.col3, two.col4))
   and (vals.val3 is null or vals.val3 in (two.col1, two.col2, two.col3, two.col4))
   and (vals.val4 is null or vals.val4 in (two.col1, two.col2, two.col3, two.col4))
;
```

Here is a [live demo of the solution](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3ecf/9)

---

My goodness, I guess I should read my own answer and do some research more often. SQLServer has a Pivot operator that makes the solution very efficient. Oracle has Pivot as well, but it uses different syntax.

Here is a [working demo of the SQLServer Pivot solution](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79fd9/29). Take a look at the sweet execution plan.

And here is the SQLServer query:

```
with 
uniqueOne as ( 
  select distinct col1 from one 
),
ranked as (
  select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) seq from uniqueOne
),
vals as (
  select [1] val1, [2] val2, [3] val3, [4] val4, [5] val5
    from ranked
    pivot ( min(col1) for seq in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) ) PivotTable
)
select two.*
  from two
  join vals on val5 is null
 where (vals.val1 is null or vals.val1 in (two.col1, two.col2, two.col3, two.col4))
   and (vals.val2 is null or vals.val2 in (two.col1, two.col2, two.col3, two.col4))
   and (vals.val3 is null or vals.val3 in (two.col1, two.col2, two.col3, two.col4))
   and (vals.val4 is null or vals.val4 in (two.col1, two.col2, two.col3, two.col4))
;
```